# Fileupload of GWT throwing error after chrome update 38.0.2125.101

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, file-upload

I recently updated my chrome to 38.0.2125.101 and tried to upload a zip file to my web application which is built using GWT(Google Web ToolKit) . The following error was thrown.
"
Unable to read zip file
abc.zip
Failed to construct 'Text Decoder' : Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
"
However it worked well in the previous version of chrome.
Just to verify i installed an available older version 28.0.1500.71.and it worked fine here too
I used the [fileupload](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) object to provide the upload feature.
The webapplication provides an option to select whichever files the user wants to be selected after unzipping the zip file uploaded and lists them.  However this exception is thrown and the screen which is supposed to list the unzipped list of files does not show. 
Can anyone comment on why this is happening?

Comment: Tested my installation here on Chrome 38.0.2125.101 and the fileupload still works just fine. Are you sure it's caused by fileupload and not by something going wrong on the server?

Comment: I am positive about that. As, the same code works fine on previous versions and the error is thrown only on the latest update of chrome.

Comment: Does the request actually reach the server or does it already fail on the client?

Comment: The error is being thrown because of the [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/)  library. 
The exact line throwing the exception is-var zip = new JSZip(xyz);
Still cant figure out the reason as to why this is happening. As it works completely fine in the previous versions.

Comment: I've never used that library, so I can't really help you here... sorry.